# Rails showing information in a JQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have resolved this problem check below for the amended codes.
The issue was with building a single page create, update and delete function using Jquery dialog.
The full working code can be found here.
https://github.com/frozzie/ModalCrud

I am working on a single page crud.

Currently, I am trying to get the show button click to show user information on the same page in the dialog rather than on another page.

I could get the dialog working but I face problems getting the data to show.
The dialog pops up but the information is missing.

I figured that it might be due to my referencing as I still can't say that I am familiar with referencing across different file formats on Rails but I am not sure what variable names I should be referencing to.

Essentially my question would be getting the equivalent of $('#<%= dom_id @user%>') for javascript in .html.erb

Here are the relevant codes.

This is the partial that I render in the dialog. The @user does not seem to be referencing to anything. 
I have tried $('#<%= dom_id @user%>') but I am not too sure on how to use it correctly.

```
 <p>
   <b>User name:</b>
   <%= @user.user_name %>
 </p>

<p>
  <b>Email:</b>
  <%= @user.email %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Password:</b>
  <%= @user.password %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Account type:</b>
  <%= @user.account_type %>
</p>
```

This is my show.js.erb

```
$( "#show-form" ).dialog( "open" );
```

This is my dialog codes:

```
 $( "#show-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        resizable:false,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    })
```

And this is my form which will appear as a dialog on click of show.

```
<div id="show-form" title="User Information"><%= render :partial => "userinfo"%></div>
```

Any help on how I could change this to show the information in a dialog would be appreciated.

---

The corrected codes:
Instead of rendering it as a partial I included the dialog form inside.
The idea to render the dialog for each user.

```
  <tr id = "<%= dom_id user%>">
    <td><%= user.user_name %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.password %></td>
    <td><%= user.account_type %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user, :remote=>true%></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user), :remote => true %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, :remote => true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </td> 
    <div id = "show-form">
    <p>
    <b>User name:</b>
      <%= user.user_name %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <b>Email:</b>
      <%= user.email %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <b>Password:</b>
      <%= user.password %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <b>Account type:</b>
      <%= user.account_type %>
    </p></div>
    </tr>
```

This is the javascript for the dialog.

```
        $( "#show-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        resizable:false,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                //$("#new_user")[0].reset();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    })
```

This happens on click.

```
$("#show-form").dialog( "open" );
```

Comment: You can try to use data attributes to pass data to javascript http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Hmm, not sure how I could go about using it. I would probably need the id only though.  For example, $('#<%= dom_id @user%>').fadeOut(); works in javascript. But I am not sure how I could do the same to the html.erb file such that I can get <%= @user.user_name %>

Comment: How you call html.erb file?

Comment: <div id="show-form" title="User Information"><%= render :partial => "userinfo"%></div> Here, I rendered a partial in my index page.

Comment: you can also try to pass data as local variables http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials (find sections about local variables)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I realised my mistake. I had to render a different form for each user. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
$( "#show-form" ).dialog( "open" );
```

Your "#show-form" must be already rendered in a page. It may be invisible ("display: none;"), but it should be known by browser.

So, in the users list:

```
<% users.each do |user| %>
   <div id="<%= dom_id(user) %>" title="User Information" style="display: none;"><%= render :partial => "userinfo", :user => user %></div>
<% end %>
```

In the "userinfo" change '@user' to 'user'.

In any Javascript helper create universal dialog caller function:

```
function show_as_dialog(dom_id) {
  $(dom_id).dialog( "open" );
}
```

And link "Show" (for each 'user'):

```
<%= link_to_function "Show", raw("show_as_dialog('#{dom_id(user)}')") %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, by changing '@user' to 'user', I get this message undefined local variable or method `user'.

Comment: Look up: <%= render :partial => "userinfo", :user => user %>

Comment: Hi I can't seem to solve that error message but I have decided that instead of rendering a partial I included the user info div inside my tr. Thanks alot btw!
I will edit my codes above.